# Using Scala Primitives inside Java 8 Lambda is causing Serialization exception in Spark

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-spark

I am working on a codebase that is using Java 8 with Spark 1.5. I need to interface with a Scala library which is returning `Function[A,B]` so I wrote a little function that converts `Function[A,B]` to `Functional[A,B]` as follow

```
 implicit def toJavaFunction[A, B](fn: A => B): Function[A, B] = new Function[A, B] {
    override def apply(t: A): B = fn(t)
  }
```

when I pass this function to Spark and `B` is `AnyVal` such as `Long` or `Int` it result in Serialization exception, however when i manually box it to `java.lang.Integer` etc it works fine

so for example code below results in an exception

```
case class User(name:String,age:Int)
val fn: (e:User) => e.age
```

> //implicitly converted to Java and passed to spark // exception caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
>   java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field
>   com.a.b.v.aggregators.Aggregator$2.val$fn of type
>   java.util.function.Function in instance of
>   com.a.b.v.aggregators.Aggregator$2.val$fn     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)

however if i do the following, it works fine

```
val fn: (e:User) => e.age:java.lang.Integer
```

Is there a way I can fix this or force autoboxing so I dont have to do `e.age:java.lang.Integer` everytime I call the function